# Clojure beginner here. Cannot figure out why function is not creating list as expected

Tags: clojure, lisp

I'm trying to add a nested vector into a map i.e.({:cells {[x y]}).  I've attempted to do this in multiple ways but no matter what I am trying I cannot get it to work.  I keep getting "Wrong number of args (0) passed to: clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap" or in another case I cannot even get my remaining functions i.e.(coordinates-gen) to compile it seems.  I have to reenter them manually in order to get the REPL to recognize them.  I'm really a beginner to serious coding in general so I don't know quite else where to turn.  Here is my function:

```
(defn values-manual [grid values]
  (let [inter (interleave (coordinates-gen grid) [values])]
    (loop [[x y & remaining] inter]
      do(
         (assoc grid :cells (x y))
         (recur remaining)))))
```

I've chosen to interleave the two vectors (grid and values) together as they may not be the same size and interleave automatically truncates to the smaller, which is desirable for my output.  I then access the first two elements of this list.  Then associate them with the :cells key in my "grid" map.  Then repeat on the remaining elements.  As soon as I try to run this it won't work and my other defined functions are not recognized.  I also used a do() because I could verify if loop works on more than one function.  What is going on? Really appreciate any help.

I tried everything I could think of.  This is my first big coding project.

Comment: Could you describe the whole problem you're trying to solve, and also provide some example data and expected results for them? We even don't know what function `coordinates-gen` does (or should do). And it would help you to break your problem into smaller parts and test them one by one in REPL- that `do()` isn't even Clojure syntax.

Comment: If you generate your coordinates as pairs and not flat, you can `zipmap` the coords with the values

Answer (score 6):

Since the code you've posted doesn't compile -- it produces `Syntax error: Can only recur from tail position` -- I'm going to assume you meant `(do` rather than `do(`.

Fixing that doesn't produce the error you're seeing but I suspect `((assoc grid :cells (x y)))` would lead to the `Wrong number of args (0) passed to: clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap`.

In Clojure, parentheses matter: you can't add extra ones and you can't omit them either -- they need to be in the right place.

When you have `(expr)` it's going to invoke `expr` as a function. When you have `((assoc ...))`, it's going to evaluate `(assoc ...)` to produce a hash map *and then invoke that hash map as a function with no arguments* which is what causes that error.

The other issue you're having -- which is very common for people coming to Clojure from other languages -- is that data is immutable so `assoc` does not modify `grid`, it returns a new hash map with the additional `:cells` entry added. And because you have `(do (assoc ...) (recur ...))` it effectively throws away that new value and loops again with remaining.

Your `loop` / `recur` needs to keep the accumulated value in addition to the `remaining` elements, and then have an `if` so you return the accumulated value when `remaining` is empty.

That `(x y)` is probably wrong too since it will try to invoke (the value of) `x` as a function with a single argument `y`. Perhaps you mean `[x y]` which will be a pair with the values of `x` and `y` in it?

Comment: Thank you, that sounds really good.  I will try this and get back if I have problems!